# Pytest inheritance and fixtures

Tags: inheritance, pytest, fixtures, paramterized

I have a fixture that loads a yaml file,
I have abase test class
TestBaseA
ans a sublass that inherites from it, TestB(TestBaseA )
In TestB i have the function test_values():
I want to paramtrize test_values() with the config values i got from the fixture. How do i do it?
The code looks like this:

```
import pytest
import yaml
from 

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def load_config():
    with open(r"\test_plan_1.yaml") as f:
        data = yaml.safe_load(f)
    return data

class TestBase:

    def calculate_(self, test_path_1, test_path_2, window_size, threshold):
        
        return consecutive_failures

class TestB(TestBase):


    @pytest.mark.parametrize("threshold", //I want to read these values from the yaml loaded in the fixture)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("window_size", //I want to read these values from the yaml loaded in the fixture)
    def test_resulty(self, threshold, window_size,load_config):
        try:

            consecutive_failures = self.calculate_
            )
            assert consecutive_failures == 0
```

Comment: I'd agree with @VonC you should read that doc again. I have found this blog post: https://raphael.codes/blog/pytest-parametrize-with-indirect/ a bit more intelligible if that makes sense. Check also https://github.com/wolever/parameterized as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You could follow what is described in [How to parametrize fixtures and test functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html)

You cannot directly use a fixture to parametrize a test function with `@pytest.mark.parametrize` since it is designed for static values. But you can achieve a similar effect by using the [`pytest_generate_tests` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests) to *dynamically* parametrize your test based on the contents of the YAML file.

Instead of directly using the fixture to pass parameters to your test, you will load your YAML configuration in a [session-scoped fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session) (i.e. the fixture is destroyed at the end of the test session.), or directly within the `pytest_generate_tests` hook if the configuration is solely used for parametrization and not needed in the test body.

Implement the `pytest_generate_tests` hook in your `conftest.py` or test module to read the YAML data and use it to dynamically generate tests with the desired parameters:

```py
# conftest.py or within your test module
import pytest
import yaml

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'threshold' in metafunc.fixturenames or 'window_size' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        with open(r"\test_plan_1.yaml") as f:
            data = yaml.safe_load(f)
        # Assuming your YAML file structure allows direct extraction of values for parametrization
        thresholds = data['thresholds']
        window_sizes = data['window_sizes']
        if 'threshold' in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.parametrize('threshold', thresholds)
        if 'window_size' in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.parametrize('window_size', window_sizes)

# Your test module
class TestB(TestBase):

    def test_resulty(self, threshold, window_size):
        # Your test implementation
```

The `pytest_generate_tests` hook reads your YAML configuration and dynamically applies parametrization to your tests based on the contents.

In detail:

`pytest_generate_tests` is a hook function that `pytest` calls when collecting a test function. That happens before any test is actually executed.
During the test collection phase, `pytest` identifies all the test functions and classes in the specified directories and files. For each collected test function, `pytest` checks if there is a `pytest_generate_tests` function defined in the `conftest.py` files or directly in the test modules.
If `pytest_generate_tests` is found, `pytest` invokes it, passing a [`metafunc` object](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) as the argument. That `metafunc` object contains metadata about the test function including its name, the fixture names it uses, and a method to parametrize the test function (`metafunc.parametrize()`).
Inside `pytest_generate_tests`, you can use `metafunc.parametrize()` to dynamically generate parameters for the test functions based on your custom logic. You can access the command-line arguments, read files, or generate data programmatically to decide the parameters.